# Why does Baze reverse Chirrut's chant?

Tags: star-wars, the-force, rogue-one

Chirrut chants

> *"I am one with The Force, and The Force is with me."*

Baze says

> *"The Force is with me, and I am one with The Force."*

I'm sure there must be meaning in it. **Why the reversal?**

Comment: I'm not sure a lot of meaning can be derived in the 120 seconds or so between their deaths.

Comment: Baze's death made me think of Bushido... It certainly seemed meaningful to him @Terriblefan

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The novelization indicates that the reversed version is intended as the "response" in a "[call-and-response](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_and_response)" phrasing (emphasis mine):

> Baze Malbus cradled the last true Guardian of the Whills in his arms and **answered** Chirrut's dying words. "The Force is with me," Baze said. "And I am one with the Force."
>
> <sup>*Rogue One: A Star Wars Story - Official Novelization* Chapter 20</sup>

Call-and-response isn't [a terribly uncommon](https://www.google.ca/search?q=call%20and%20response%20prayer) phrase construction for prayers.

Presumably, Baze's line is the other half of Chirut's prayer, which he's just been neglecting to provide throughout the earlier parts of the film.  It's also worth noting that the Guardians of the Whills aren't unfamiliar with the use of [antimetabole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antimetabole) and [chiasmus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiasmus), as seen in another of their prayers in the novelization:

> **Supplemental Data: Sunset Prayer**
>
> *[Document #JP0103 ("Sunset Prayer of the Guardians of the Whills"), recovered from the outskirts of NiJedha; provenance uncertain.]*
>
> In darkness, cold.
> In light, cold.
> The old sun brings no heat.
> But there is heat in breath and life.
> In life, there is the Force.
> In the Force, there is life.
> And the Force is eternal.
>
> <sup>*Rogue One: A Star Wars Story - Official Novelization* Supplemental Data: Sunset Prayer</sup>